# Compile a list of unique objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5

Having the pseudo code

```
class Bar {int BarId;}

class Foo {
  List<Bar> Bars;
}
```

Using Linq, how should I select all avaiable unique bars from the foo list ?

```
List<Foo> foos = GetFoos(); // anything

List<Bar> allBars = foos.Select(f=>f.Bars)...?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) Linq method like below:

```
List<Bar> allBars = foos.SelectMany(f => f.Bars).ToList();
```

If you need distinct instance of Bar in your list so add [`Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8) like below:

```
List<Bar> allBars = foos.SelectMany(f => f.Bars).Distinct().ToList();
```

Source [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8):

> If you want to return distinct elements from sequences of objects of
>   some custom data type, you have to implement the IEquatable generic
>   interface in the class.

Comment: distict should use a comparer then?

Comment: I just want to say, distict by BarId, what is the need to build an interface for this?

Comment: @Serge you don't need to define a new interface but Bar class should implement IEquatable<Bar> that all.

Comment: @Serge you can use `.GroupBy(bar => bar.Id, (k, g) => g.FirstOrDefault())` isntead of `Distinct`. Alternatively, you can use `DistinctBy(bar => bar.Id)` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq